# How to do conditional check using history.back() in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to check if the url is 'a' then redirect to 'b'?

I am able to go back but when the url is meetingRoom , I want to redirect to people page.

Here is the code--

```
         <Button onClick={goBack} className="dis-in-flex align-items-center">
          <i className="ac-icon-back" />
          <span className="m-l-5">Back</span>
        </Button>
```

//goBack

```
      const goBack = () => {
        history.back();
      };
```

Comment: What is `history` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms it's the history api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Comment: Check the current path by ```history.location.pathname```. And depending on the value, push ```history.push("/someValue")```

Comment: @Melchia could also be https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history that's why I asked ...

Comment: It's based on the History API. It would work either way.

Comment: @Melchia no, not necessarily.

Comment: Whatever, this sounds as if you should do it the other way round: When opening this page from all other pages, use `history.push`, when visiting it from the meetingRoom use `history.replace` such that going back goes to the previous page (which I suspect is the people page)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you configured your application. But you can use [window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) to check if you're in page `meetingRoom` and then either go back or redirect to the new URL:

```
 const goBack = () => {
        if (window.location.pathname.includes('meetingRoom') {
             window.location.replace('/peoplePage');
        }
        else {
            history.back();
        }
      };
```